# Android MVVM pattern: where to start activity for result?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

In the MVVM architecture, where does one start an activity for result ? For example, I need to get banking informations from an nfc tag in my payment app. What I do is I start the ReadNFCActivity from my PaymentActivity, retrieve the results there, and then I call my PaymentViewModel's updatePaymentInformations(name: String, account_number: Int...) method from my PaymentActivity. The data going from one activity to the other before being sent to the viewModel doesn't feel like the right way. How would you structure this ?

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you receiving help from others and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: It may not perfectly fit MVVM where the V is your Activity, but there’s no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

In MVVV you shouldn't gather or keep data in your views. In your example you shouldn't get data from the card in the view. You can get the data from the card in the viewmodel and save in a Livedata variable. Whenever you need to display the data you can observe this Livedata. Handling the data this way can help you in complicate lifecycle aware data management scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for your response ! How would I gather the data directly in the view model ? Should the ReadNFCActivity called by my PaymentActivity call a readNfc() function in the viewModel, for example ? But isn't a viewModel supposed to be attached to a single activity ? I guess I should remake my ReadNFCActivity as a fragment of PaymentActivity ?

Comment: You can attach more than one activity to a viewmodel. Another solution is using fragments as you mentioned. Also, because the business of calling another activity should be implemented in the viewmodel in MVVM, you can pass the data in a bundle. In my opinion the best option is using fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to think of Activities as containing a view not the view itself. Meaning showing stuff on the screen is not it's only purpose it is also a/the context of the app which allows access to OS functionality and resources.

Unlike Windows where you can access OS functionality and resources anywhere making MVVM trivial, instead in Android you have to access it through a context, which is the Activity/Application.

IMO

If your activity is starting another activity for a result than its well with its right to do that, because its the context. Passing that result to the view model is no different than sending input from a listener to the view model like text input.

If the view model isn't touch the views than you view model is good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I hadn't thought of it this way, but your analogy with a text input is spot on. Still, I'm wondering : could you have the two activities share the same viewmodel, in order to not have the data transit between them ? Or is there a way to get the context from the activity to the viewmodel and start a new activity from there ? Would this be against the principles of the MVVM pattern ?

Comment: Well their is the `AndroidViewModel` which gets the application context injected into it so you could start stuff within the view model. You can also pass the context of the activity as an argument to a normal view model's function so it does its thing then its out. It is also possible to use a shared view model, but those should be used sparingly as they create a light coupling between the activities. If its a single concise request just pass the result to the view model via the activity, that is the cleanest approach IMO.